# why wont the single vertex point method of drawing work now?

Tags: vertices

Reference picture of rune

[image: Reference picture of rune]

[image: reference of the rune wihtout the reference image]

[image: vertex point not working]

I am trying to make the rune inside the triangle i extruded. i already have to 2 ovals for the top part of it made but when i do add mesh, single vertex point, add vertex point it appears but i cant make any lines for the bottom part like i usually can. i have no clue why its not working now. I learned this method was good for making symbols and weird shapes through ctrl+ right mouse click.

I'm still trying to get a handle on blender. Im used to rhino 6

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your third image where you are in <kbd>Edit</kbd> mode shows that you're in <kbd>Face</kbd> select mode. Switch to <kbd>Vertex</kbd> select mode (Red box - hit <kbd>1</kbd> on the keyboard) and you should be able to see your vertices.

[image]

Comment: thanks for the help my friend. I did the homer Simpson "D'oh!" when i read my basic mistake. I feel silly now

Comment: Easily done! Adding a single vertex in Object mode automatically switches you to Edit mode with Vertex select already set, but after that it's down to you!